# Forbidden on everything except for scripts located on subfolders

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want to forbid everything coming on a specific domain (e.g. `example.com`) except for some entry points (here, PHP files) located on a specific path (e.g. `example.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php`).

Here's a snippet of the configuration I used within my virtual host for this particular domain. I still get a 403 for everything.

For context, I'm using Apache 2.4.41 + FPM 7.2

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /my/path
  <Directory /my/path>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/subfolder2$
    RewriteRule . - [F,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/subfolder2$
> RewriteRule . - [F,L]
> ```

Because of the end-of-string anchor (`$`) this only permits `/subfolder1/subfolder2` exactly (not `/subfolder1/subfolder2/script.php`) and blocks everything else. Since `/subfolder1/subfolder2` is presumably a physical directory then mod_dir will redirect to append the trailing slash, which will then be blocked by this rule. So yes, it does block *everything*.

You need to remove the end-of-string anchor (`$`) from the end of the *CondPattern*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/subfolder2
```

Although, strictly speaking, to avoid conflict with anything that might simply start with `subfolder2` (eg. `subfolder2foo.php`) then you should use a regex like `^/subfolder1/subfolder2($|/)` instead.

Note that if this is the only URL-path you need to allow the you don't need the *condition*, since the test should be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive directly. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^/subfolder1/subfolder2($|/) - [F]
```

The `L` flag is not required with the `F` flag; it is implied.

---

Alternatively, don't use mod_rewrite at all. For example:

```
  <Directory /my/path>
    Require all denied
  </Directory>
  <Directory /my/path/subfolder1/subfolder2>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

This is preferable to mod_rewrite, unless you have other requirements.

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! How can I don't think about your last solution ? so simple :D

Comment: @alxsbn Since you mentioned "subfolder**s**" it wasn't particularly clear whether the last solution would work outside of your limited example. Although you could always use `<DirectoryMatch>` and a regex if you have multiple subfolders.